# Python: adding buttons in a boxlayout that can be scrolled in a press of a button

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

ok so it might sound confusing, but i would like to add the data derived from mysql then making it a stack of buttons inside a BoxLayout that can be scrolled.
But in this problem, there are no errors but upon clicking the button, it does'nt work.

```
    def a_but(self):
        nodes = ObjectProperty()
        db = mysql.connector.connect(user='****', password='*******', host='localhost', db='***')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT Cos_name FROM costumerinfo WHERE Cos_name LIKE 'A%'")
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        if result:
            for i in result:
                self.nodes.add_widget(Button(text=i, height='200sp'))
                self.nodes.size = (1, None)
```

here is the kv file

```
     BoxLayout:
         Button:
             text: "A"
             background_color: (1, 1, 1, 0.8)
             on_release: root.a_but()
             size_hint: 1, .5
     #this is the part where the buttons should appear but in this case it doesnt 
     BoxLayout:
         orientation:'vertical'
         size_hint: 1, 1
         ScrollView:
             id: scrlv
             bar_width: 10
             BoxLayout:
                 id: nodes
                 orientation: 'vertical'
                 size_hint: 1, None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Remove the following because it will produce an error, `ValueError: None is not allowed for BoxLayout.height`

```
self.nodes.size = (1, None)
```

2) Set the *minimum height* of the boxlayout so that there is something to scroll.

```
layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
```

## Example - Kivy, SQLite

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
import sqlite3 as lite


class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
    nodes = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.nodes.bind(minimum_height=self.nodes.setter('height'))

    def a_but(self):
        ''' Retrieve from database'''

        db = lite.connect('chinook.db')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT FirstName FROM customers ORDER BY CustomerId ASC")
        result = cursor.fetchall()

        if result:
            for row in result:
                for col in row:
                    self.nodes.add_widget(Button(text=col, size_hint_y=None, height='200sp'))


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<RootWidget>:
    nodes: nodes

    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "A"
            background_color: (1, 1, 1, 0.8)
            on_release: root.a_but()
            size_hint: 1, .5

    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        size_hint: 1, 1
        ScrollView:
            id: scrlv
            bar_width: 10
            BoxLayout:
                id: nodes
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: 1, None
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - App Startup]
[image: Img02 - Scrollview]

Comment: thank you for your effort in giving time to answer this question. i would like to clarify if this would work if ever i would add an on_release value on each buttons that would add a textinput below them to display information about them.